# Confusion about Modulus Multiplication and Exponents

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I have two questions about the modulus function.

In my book (Computer Security (2nd Edition), Chapter 10, Page 314), it says that:

1847(1002, 493) mod 2503 = (460, 2083).

Note that (x, y) mod p = (x mod p, y mod p)

Why is that? I am getting a different answer on Wolfram.

Similarly, in my book, it says that (923*15653^(-3632)) mod 262643 = 152015?

Shouldn't it be equal to 0?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is (A,B) mod C?

Comment: (x, y) mod p = (x mod p, y mod p)

Comment: I think the point is that the multiple refers to the addition on the elliptic curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm, as hinted in a comment to your question, that the discrepancy arises from a misinterpretation of the notation
$$
1847 (1002, 493) \bmod 2503.
\tag{multiple}
$$

Wolfram understands this as
$$
(1847 * 1002  \bmod 2503, 1847 * 493 \bmod 2503).
$$
Fair enough - how could Wolfram know about the elliptic curve you have in mind?

The correct interpretation in the exercise is that (multiple) refers to the multiple *with respect to addition on the elliptic curve*. Please check [the formulas for point addition (and doubling) on an elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_addition).

If you wish I can provide simple [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/) code for point addition and doubling.

Comment: Got it. What about (923*15653^(-3632)) mod 262643 = 152015?

Comment: That's an entirely different cryptosystem and situation.You should first compute the *inverse modulo $p = 262643$* of $15653$, then its $3632$-th power modulo $p$, and then multiply the result by $1847$ modulo $p$.